# Infinite linear system

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra

Can Mathematica solve infinite linear systems? For example, if we have a infinite differential system, with recurrence, is it possible to solve it with Mathematica?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question without a bit more detail. Can you please give an example of such a system?

Comment: One example: $f'_n(x)=f_{n-1}(x)+Af_{n+1}(x)$. Each equation depends from two other equations in the system.

Comment: You might be interested in `RSolve`.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica can do many computations with the help of appropriate code. In your particular case, use recursion. Please try this code

```
ClearAll[f, x]; f[0] = 1; f[1] = x;
f[m_] := f[m] = Module[{fnp1, n = m - 1}, fnp1 /. 
      Solve[ D[f[n], x] == f[n - 1] + A*fnp1, fnp1][[1]]];
```

where you are free to change `f[0]` and `f[1]` to your own initial functions. Note the use of the variables `x` and `fnp1`. The `fnp1` represents `f[n+1]` but that is **not** a variable according to Mathematica. Also the use of `f[m_] := f[m] =` to preserve the results of previous calls to `f[]`.